# How to use simple node logger module

Tags: node.js, logging, morgan

This below function created mylogfile but can't error the logs of api response with timestamp and error in app

```
const SimpleNodeLogger = require('simple-node-logger'),
    opts = {
        logFilePath:'mylogfile.log',
        timestampFormat:'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss.SSS'
    },

log = SimpleNodeLogger.createSimpleLogger( opts );
```

Comment: Can you please provide more details, like where did you use SimpleNodeLogger in your app?

Comment: I am using app.js file but it will not create error logs file

https://www.npmjs.com/package/simple-node-logger

Comment: As per documentation you should use createSimpleLogger method like this one, ```log = SimpleNodeLogger.createSimpleLogger( opts );``` which i cant see it in your provided example

Comment: i have already add in my code but its not working

Comment: You need to specify your log type when you log your messages, check the doc https://www.npmjs.com/package/simple-node-logger#log-statement-formats

Answer (score 1, accepted):

seems you're missing something ... here's an example

```js
// utilities/logger.js


const SimpleNodeLogger = require('simple-node-logger');
const opts = {
    logFilePath:'mylogfile.log',
    timestampFormat:'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss.SSS'
};

const log = SimpleNodeLogger.createSimpleLogger(opts);

module.exports = log;
```

and then, just use it

```js
// index.js

const logger = require('./utilities/logger');


logger.info(`I'm an information line`);
logger.debug(`I'm a debug line`);
logger.error(`I'm an error line`);
```

that will output in a new created file called `mylogfile.log`:

```
2020-12-25 13:37:17.139 INFO  I'm an information line 
2020-12-25 13:37:17.140 ERROR I'm an error line
```

set the log level if you want to output more info, like debug. All options are in the [package page titled "How to use"](https://www.npmjs.com/package/simple-node-logger#how-to-use)

Comment: how can you know can show me detail or any info doc

Comment: I'm sorry but I didn't understand the question 

Comment: but i want to know if api's working in prodcution then how can i log my error

Comment: in production it might not work as you expect, first, you need to know if you have access to write to the server files? that's why nowadays we use a free service to send logs to, as most of the hosting companies, we can't create files... you can look at https://logentries.com/ I use it a lot, and after the trial, you have 5Gb per month for free | another way is to read the console log from the server (if you can). I use Heroku.com to host and logEntries is a free package.

Comment: ok thanks Can you give your mail id or skype id

Comment: Hello.. can you send me your id